# ORA-00001: unique constraint when trying to insert data even when table data deleted with commit

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to migrate data from one table in one db to an identical test db.  Each table is the same, in fact, the schemas are identical for both databases.

I've deleted data from the table in my test db and run the commit statement:

```
DELETE TESTDB.MYTABLE; COMMIT;
```

This table has a PK so another table that would have an foreign key based on the primary key would cause the constraint error, as I've read.  But, this doesn't appear to be the case.

So, my question is, are there other reasons that this that would cause this error constraint?

Error messages reads:
Error: ORA-24381: error(s) in array DML

ORA-00001: unique constraint (db.MYTABLE_PK) violated at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: What is the actual statement that causes the error? And what is the full error? The DDL for the table and its constraints/indexes might be helpful too. Please add that info as an edit to the question.

Comment: Error: ORA-24381: error(s) in array DML

ORA-00001: unique constraint (db.MYTABLE_PK) violated at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: if you are loading an array of values, perhaps there are 2 or more rows in the array that have the same pk value...

Comment: You really need to show your code. I'd guess that you're populating the array in batches in a loop, and on the last loop you are partially filling the array but still have old values from the last loop in later positions. But that's really just a guess. Something is off with the array population, anyway, leading to duplicates somewhere.

Comment: In SQL Server, this can be caused by sneaky triggers doing unexpected things to other tables. However it appears that the constraint name correlates with your table, and I think @AlexPoole is on the right track - since your error is a application code error, it's likely the error is in your (unposted) code